# Edit item description in array in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add an edit function to a task app with Vue JS.

1. I have a click event on the edit button - `@click="editShow"` which shows the input for editing for all items. I need this to only show the corresponding input.
2. Then I cannot get the edit value to save to the items description - `@keyup.enter="editTask"`. For some reason the task refers to the keyup event and not the object. I think that's what is causing the problem.

Here is what I have so far, https://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/0p6bvd4j/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container" id="tasks">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            {{ message }}
        </h3>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix" v-for="task in tasklist" >
            <strong v-if="!editActive">{{ task.description }}</strong>
            <input v-model="editTaskName" v-bind:placeholder="task.description" v-if="editActive" @keyup.enter="editTask" type="text" class="form-control input-height pull-left">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right" role="group" v-if="!task.completed">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="completeTask(task)">Complete</button>
              <button type="button" @click="editShow" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="removeTask(task)">Remove</button>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm completed text-muted pull-right disabled btn-width" v-else>Completed</button>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
            <input v-model="newTaskName" @keyup.enter="newTask" type="text" class="form-control input-height pull-left">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right btn-width" @click="newTask">Add Task</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
    new Vue({

    el: '#tasks',

    data: {
        message: 'Tasks',
        completed: null,
        newTaskName: '',
        editTaskName: '',
        editActive: false,
        tasklist: [
            { description: 'Read', completed: true },
            { description: 'Write', completed: true },
            { description: 'Edit', completed: false },
            { description: 'Publish', completed: false }
        ]
    },

    methods: {
        completeTask: function(task){
            task.completed = true;
        },
        newTask: function(){
            this.tasklist.push({description: this.newTaskName, completed: false});
        },
        removeTask: function(task){
            this.tasklist.splice(this.tasklist.indexOf(task), 1);
            console.log(task);
        },
        editShow: function(task){
            this.editActive = true // should only show the corresponding edit input
            console.log(task);
        },
        editTask: function(task){
            console.log(task);
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added a `editing` boolean to your tasks. You can toggle that to swap the individual tasks to edit mode. Additionally, I pass the task through your `editTask` on the `keyup.enter`. Finally, since using `v-model` on your input, there's no saving that needs to be done because the description is two-way bound. Your enter keyup handler just needs to toggle the mode back.

```js
new Vue({

    el: '#tasks',

    data: {
        message: 'Tasks',
        completed: null,
        newTaskName: '',
        tasklist: [
            { description: 'Read', completed: true, editing: false },
            { description: 'Write', completed: true, editing: false  },
            { description: 'Edit', completed: false, editing: false  },
            { description: 'Publish', completed: false, editing: false  }
        ]
    },

    methods: {
        completeTask: function(task){
            task.completed = true;
        },
        newTask: function(){
            this.tasklist.push({description: this.newTaskName, completed: false, editing: false});
        },
        removeTask: function(task){
            this.tasklist.splice(this.tasklist.indexOf(task), 1);
            console.log(task);
        },
        editTask: function(task){
            task.editing = false;
            console.log(task);
        }
    }

})
```

```css
 body{
  margin-top: 4em;
 }
 .completed{
  text-decoration: line-through;
 }
 .btn-width{
  width: 182px;
 }
 .input-height{
  width: 346px !important;
  height: 30px;
 }
 .container{
  width: 600px;
 }
 strong{
  line-height: 2.2;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="tasks">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            {{ message }}
        </h3>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix" v-for="task in tasklist" >
            <strong v-if="!task.editing">{{ task.description }}</strong>
            <input v-model="task.description" v-if="task.editing" @keyup.enter="editTask(task)" type="text" class="form-control input-height pull-left">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right" role="group" v-if="!task.completed">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="completeTask(task)">Complete</button>
              <button type="button" @click="task.editing = true" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="removeTask(task)">Remove</button>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm completed text-muted pull-right disabled btn-width" v-else>Completed</button>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
            <input v-model="newTaskName" @keyup.enter="newTask" type="text" class="form-control input-height pull-left">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right btn-width" @click="newTask">Add Task</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @ClintonGreen no problem :) There are other ways it could work, but that's the first that came to mind. There's some cleanup that needs to be done. When you add a new task, should set the editing value for example.

Comment: Yeah thanks easy as to do, you've done all the heavy lifting. Cheers

Comment: @Bert it doesn't seem like the example quite works as expected.  When I tried adding an item in the fiddle, then try to edit said item, the editor doesn't open.

Comment: @user1477388 You're right, there is a bug. It's here: `this.tasklist.push({description: this.newTaskName, completed: false,});` When the fiddle is adding a new item it does not have an `editing` property. Adding the `editing` property and defaulting it to false, corrects that bug. The correct code is in the answer, but not in the fiddle.

Comment: @Bert Nice!  Thanks for updating it!